# Any CAPL function to disable logging block when simulation is ON and activate it back required?

Tags: logging, capl, canoe, automotive, canalyzer

Trying to take logs in .pcap format n post process from trace window, I'm using startlogging and stoplogging capl functions as of now . When I'm stopping it pauses and resumes when I start again. I want it to be overwritten again when I start it. Need capl functions.

Comment: Well the CAPL functions to start and stop logging are `startLogging` and `stopLogging`. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: As I mentioned in the query I want the file to be overwritten, I don't want it to pause and resume with same old file.Now  It's like dumping the packets into existing file instead of overwriting. Do we have any function in capl to remove the logging block and add it back when required?

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the log file before starting the logging block again.

The CAPL call to do so is `closeLogFile(<loggingBlockName>)`

When you call `startLogging` again after closing, the old file will be overwritten.

---

If you use CANoe earlier than version 17 `closeLogFile` is not available.

Then your only option is to rename or delete the logfile before calling `startLogFile`. E.g.:

```
sysExecCmd("del", "<path to log file>")
startLogging(<loggingBlockName>);
```

Comment: I dont find any capl function called closeLogFile. It is capl function?

Comment: @Sindhu Yes, it is a CAPL function. However only introduced with CANoe 17. If you are on an earlier version, you would have to delete the logfile. I have adapted my answer.

Comment: We can't delete the file when we are using it for logging..

Comment: when the simulation is ON we cant delete or move  the file from the specified location since logging is happening from canoe(the file is being used by canoe ) , we are getting permission error. We are copying the file to different location and using it as of now. Thanks for your suggestion..